# OSX 10.5 Leopard to Failover Clustered Windows FIle Share Error 6602

Tags: mac-osx, windows-server-2008-r2, file-sharing, failovercluster

I have set up a failover-clustered file share on a pair of Windows Server 2008 R2 Machines.  This setup is working very well with all of the Windows clients that I know of, as well as with Macs running 10.6 Snow Leopard.  However, the Macs on our network that are running 10.5 Leopard are *not* connecting as they should.

I don't expect that the failover-clustered part of the equation is causing any issues, but I thought that in the off chance that it may be causing issues, to include it here to provide a hint to whoever is willing to help.

When a machine running Leopard attempts to connect, it trys for a bit, then asks for the username and password to connect with (as expected).  The username and password are entered (correctly), and almost immediately it comes back with the message `A volume failed to mount.  The volume "Home" could not be mounted.`

When that box is dismissed, it continues to attempt to connect for a short time, then it comes up with this `unexpected error`:

[image: Error code -6602]

A couple of Google searches have not come up with anything (for me) about `Error code -6602`.

Any ideas what this error may be, and/or how I should go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a [bug](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverClustering/thread/ccae8d95-4e49-4e2e-8c13-cd9bd8cc54ba) with 10.5.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to figure this out. It is indeed something to do with Failover Clustering.  Because it is clustered, it must be accessed by name, and 10.5 tries to connect using the translated IP.  The work-around is to connect directly to a share, adding the NetBIOS port number to the mix like so: `smb://fileserver:139/sharename`.  Thank You, Scott.